# xamarin.forms : ListView not updating as expexcted

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have built a app using Xamarin.Forms that I am displaying in Windows.
Requirement: 
- tap on item in the ListView > 
- the displayed value for the item changes in the UI

Here is the relevant xaml
NOTE: I have set the ListView.ItemsSource from code behind

```
  <ListView.ItemTemplate > 
  <StackLayout  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"  >
  <Label Text="Passo dopo passo" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
  <Button Clicked="GetGroceries" Text="Get Groceries" ></Button>
  <ListView x:Name="lvGroceries" ItemTapped="GroceryItemTapped" >
  <ListView.ItemTemplate >
```

Here is the c# code behind, which runs fine when the item is tapped, but the UI does not change.

```
    public ObservableCollection oc;
    public void GroceryItemTapped (object o, ItemTappedEventArgs e )
    {
     if (e.Item == null ) {
         return;
     }
     var g = ((GroceryItem)e.Item);
     // oc is populated and exactly what I expect here
     foreach (var gr in oc)
     {
         // the next line grabs the item I want
         if (gr.GroceryId == g.GroceryId)
         {
             gr.GroceryName = "snot";
         }  } }

    // when the above code runs, the data is already in oc and this code ran
    lvGroceries.ItemsSource = oc;
```

Ideas?

Comment: does GroceryItem implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your `ListView` to your collection:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvGroceries" ItemsSource="{Binding oc}" ItemTapped="GroceryItemTapped" >
```

You also need to set your `ContentPage.BindingContext`. You also need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and run `OnPropertyChanged()` anytime your collection is updated. Finally, you need to add to your collection by doing `oc.Add()` instead of reseting the `ItemSource` every time because that will overwrite your binding.

Highly suggest looking through the [Xamarin Forms Binding Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/).

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.  I will be trying that.  Of course I have been studying the Xamarin Docs.  It would be irresponsible of me to ask a question here unless I had tried that.

Comment: OK.  I only had to do one of the 4 things you mentioned, but you get the green checkmark.

I had a class, GroceryItem,  and I had to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in that class and fire the OnPropertyChanged event for the property I was changing.

This msdn doc really helped me.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @pdschuller Glad it helped and thanks for adding the link for others! Let me know if you run into any more issues with it.

Comment: Thanks for the offer to help on related issues.  I have another post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40558962/inotifypropertychanged-xamarin-string-value-just-disappears