# INotifyPropertyChanged Xamarin string value just disappears

Tags: xamarin, data-binding

I have a Xamarin.Forms project with a ListView populated with an ObservableCollection.  The class (object) that is each item in the ObservableCollection implements INotifyPropertyChanged.  A Color property toggles fine in the UI but a string property disappears and never returns.

I get the initial values from a webservice but then just do a completely static change of the values, for debugging and I still can't figure it out.

At the top of the my ContentPage class I have this:

```
public ObservableCollection<GroceryItem> oc;
```

After my webservice has returned with the data I put the data in the ObservableCollection and make that, the ItemsSource for the listview. Like this:

```
lvGroceries.ItemsSource = oc;
```

All that works great.

The XAML

```
    <ListView x:Name="lvGroceries" ItemTapped="GroceryPdsItemTapped" >               
  <ListView.ItemTemplate > 
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>              
        <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="Fill">
          <Label Text="{Binding GroceryName}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,200,40" ></Label>
          <Label Text="{Binding strHomeLoc}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="200,0,100,40" ></Label>
          <Label Text="{Binding isNeeded}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="300,0,50,40" ></Label>                
          <Label Text="someText" BackgroundColor="{Binding myBackgroundColor}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="350,0,50,40" ></Label>
        </AbsoluteLayout>        
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The class - GroceryItem

```
public class GroceryItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public GroceryItem() { }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string privateIsNeeded;
    public string isNeeded
    {
        get { return privateIsNeeded; }
        set
        {
            privateIsNeeded = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private Color theColor;
    public Color myBackgroundColor
    {
        get { return theColor; }
        set
        {
            theColor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

The click handler.  I grab an item from the ObservableCollection and change the two properties.

```
    public void GroceryPdsItemTapped(object obj, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    var g = ((GroceryItem)e.Item);
    foreach (var gr in oc)
    {
        if (gr.GroceryId == "27769")
        {   // the UI changes because the myBackgroundColor property in the GroceryItem class is watching for a value change
            gr.myBackgroundColor = (gr.myBackgroundColor == Color.Yellow) ? Color.Blue : Color.Yellow;
            gr.isNeeded = (gr.isNeeded == "true" || gr.isNeeded == "blah" || gr.isNeeded == "false") ? "notblah" : "blah";
        }
    }
}
```

The Color toggles fine in the UI but the isNeeded string value disappears on the first tap and never re-appears

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple issues here. First is that you need to make your `ObservableCollection` run `OnPropertyChanged()` when it has been changed like so:

```
private ObservableCollection<GroceryItem> _oc;

public ObservableCollection<GroceryItem> oc {
    get { return _oc ?? (_oc = new ObservableCollection<GroceryItem>()); }
    set {
        if(_oc != value) {
            _oc = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you should really have all of this in a ViewModel but since you do not, you need to set your `ContentPage` as the `BindingContext` from within your code-behind like this:

```
public partial class MyGroceryPage : ContentPage {

    public MyGroceryPage() { BindingContext = this; }
}
```

You also need to be binding your `ObservableCollection` to your `ListView.ItemSource` instead of assigning it. That looks like this:

```
<ListView ItemSource="{Binding oc}"/>
```

If you do the above and then you go into your code behind and execute `lvGroceries.ItemsSource = oc;` then that would overwrite the binding that you did in your XAML, so **do not** do that. Instead, when you get data from your web service, you would just assign it to your existing `ObservableCollection`:

```
public async Task GetGroceryData() {
    List<GroceryItem> myData = await GroceryService.GetGroceriesAsync();

    oc = new ObservableCollection<GroceryItem>(myData);
}
```

Try all of that first and if your items are still not updating you might want to try removing them from your `ObservableCollection`, changing the properties, then adding them back in:

```
public void GroceryPdsItemTapped(object obj, ItemTappedEventArgs e) {

    if (e.Item == null) { return; }

    var g = ((GroceryItem)e.Item);

    foreach (var gr in oc.ToList()) {

        if (gr.GroceryId == "27769") {   // the UI changes because the myBackgroundColor property in the GroceryItem class is watching for a value change
            oc.Remove(gr);
            gr.myBackgroundColor = (gr.myBackgroundColor == Color.Yellow) ? Color.Blue : Color.Yellow;
            gr.isNeeded = (gr.isNeeded == "true" || gr.isNeeded == "blah" || gr.isNeeded == "false") ? "notblah" : "blah";
            oc.Add(gr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to do all the steps.  Apparently, I have a lot to learn.
The Remove-Edit-Replace code could not be done in the foreach loop because the oc was tied up w the foreach, so I did this: 
`code`
var itemIndex = oc.IndexOf(g);
oc.RemoveAt(itemIndex);
// edit the item 
oc.Insert(itemIndex, g);
`code`
Thanks tons @hvaughan3

Comment: @pdschuller No problem. Glad it helped. Took me quite a while to feel comfortable with binding and everything involved with it. And yea, I have run into the `foreach` issue as well, usually I can do `foreach (var gr in oc.ToList())` (note the `ToList()`) which causes a new `List<>` to be created which gets around that issue but sounds like you figured it out.